# How to do unit test in IOS using XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, tdd, xctest

I am writing unit tests for my existing application's functionality.

I don't know how to write unit test for

- Picking an item from Gallery
- Sending sms/mail
- Making a call
- Opening
  an application

I have functions that does above things.
some things require manual intervention for example the first item requires user to make an action.

Any ideas on writing the unit test case would be great help for me.

Comment: Look into "mocking". Only worry about unit testing *your* code, mocking the rest.

Comment: sorry, but your question seems not to fit StackOverflow asking rules, please have a check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help), you can't ask for a tutorial, but we can help you fixing issues

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - Thanks for responding But how to do mocking for this scenarios Can you help me with detailed answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me, it would be difficult to write a unit test case which requires user intervention. `Basically, unit tests are written to test the entire functionality of the application (mostly positive scenarios) and check whether you get expected result. It is the means by which you can ensure that your functionality works and used many a times while building the project.`

That is, unit tests are executed before the project is deployed and are also executed more in development phase where a developer needs to run all the unit test cases to ensure that his/her changes has not affected the rest of the application functionality.

Unit tests have to be complete in their own sense, meaning for a particular test case, this the input and this is the output received, period! and nothing else.

For complete automated tests, where you can incorporate dynamic user `inputs you can maybe think of using Selenium or other frameworks or you will have to write wrappers for your own or can just simulate the user input while reading or writing the user input from certain external file or like that`.

Like, you can give some arbitrary input from a file or voice record when you make a call...OR pick some pre determined image from the gallery and test whether your application works as expected

**What I want to suggest from this answer is that, according to me, the complete idea of unit testing is different from testing which requires user intervention.**  I may be wrong with my assumptions!

Comment: Ok.But how to do unit testing for scenarios that requires picking a image ?